# How to set the variable correctly if the class has a Builder pattern which I cannot use

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple DTO class. `Movie`
https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/common/dto/Movie.java This class has a Builder pattern, to create an object you must specify two mandatory parameters in the constructor `title` and `type`. The entity `MovieEntity` is mapped to the DTO `Movie` class here https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/core/jpa/service/ServiceUtils.java within line `71`. The ServiceUtils class is not a Spring component, but just a regular Utils class.

I now want to add a rating field for the logged in user to the DTO Movie class.

```
private Float yourRating;
```

This assessment of the logged-in user will be obtained by downloading a user' rating for movie from Spring Security

```
Float yourRating = movieSearchService.getRating(principalLoggedUser, movieId);
```

I can not set `myRating` fields in any way using the `Builder` pattern in the `ServiceUtils` class, because the method accepts only the entities of the movie.
There is only one way I can think of it.

```
public Movie getMovie(
        @Min(1) final Long id
) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    log.info("Called with id {}", id);

    Movie movie = ServiceUtils.toMovieDto(this.findMovie(id));
    movie.setYourRating(movieSearchService.getRating(principalLoggedUser, movieId));
    return movie;
}
```

What do you think about the basic data for a DTO object set with the help of the Builder pattern, and then set yourRating field with a setter. Does not it look a bit strange? Or maybe you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Does it make really sense to define the `Movie` class an information related to the specific connected user ?
Conceptually, these are distinct things.
Introducing a class as `MovieUserRating` (using Builder or not) seems a better alternative and could probably solve your issue.

---

In your actual proposition, you lose the main advantages of the builder pattern (immutability, thread-safety, consistent state).
I am not sure that it be helpful to keep it as a builder under these conditions.
As alternative, you could refactor the `ServiceUtils` class to accept a overload version of `toMovieDto()`:

```
Float yourRating = movieSearchService.getRating(principalLoggedUser, movieId);
Movie movie = ServiceUtils.toMovieDtoWithRating(this.findMovie(id), yourRating);
```

In this way, you could still use the builder pattern with an additional property to set.

Comment: This first way seems a bit strange to me. If the website client is not logged in as a user, there will be no rating for the logged in user on the video page. On the other hand, if the customer decides to log in, their evaluation will be visible. 

The second way also doesn't suit me a bit, because what if the client is not logged in, then there is no `principalLoggedUser` object and they invoked `NULL`.

Comment: If you go to a film page on IMDB, you will not be rated there. But if you log in to your account, and rate the video then it will be your rating on the movie page. I don't know who should design it well.

Comment: `Does it make really sense to define the Movie class an information related to the specific connected user ?` For example, in the StackExchange API https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer the `Answer` object has private information. For me, in `Movie`, private information is `yourRating`.

Comment: I think that it is before all a point of view. Do you want to reuse the same class for specific version of it. In terms of OOP, no. In terms of code simplicity to display/update it, maybe.

Comment: To answer to the last comment, the Answer object contains information related to the Answer. It will not contain only your comment  but all of them associated to this Answer.

Comment: So do you think that I should create a second `MovieUserRating` object with all the fields of the `Movie` + field `yourRating` ? But the controller returns the object `Movie` https://github.com/JonkiPro/REST-Web-Services/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/web/web/controller/MovieRestController.java `line 178`.

Comment: I think that both approaches are valid (splitting the class or gathering in that). About splitting way, you could define `MovieUserRating`  or rather `UserMovie` a subclass of Movie. In this way you return the one or the other.

Comment: If I have to return separate objects from the controller for the logged in user and for not logged in, how should I do it? I have only one address `/ movies / {id}`

Comment: Define the parent type as return of the method. You could so return the parent or the subclass instance.